# Migrate user accounts on Server 2003 using ADMT, cannot find source domain

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts

I'm having trouble running ADMT in that I can't find the source domain. On the source computer I've looked up the domain as xxx.local and placed xxx into the Source 'Domain' name but it doesn't show me any names for domain controller.

What could be reasons why the domain doesn't show up on the target computer? What are some steps I can take to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have DNS setup for each of the domains.  In the source domain, you need either a stub zone or conditional forwarder for the target domain, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two domains are in separate forests, you need to create a trust between the two domains. Part of this involves creating DNS conditional forwarders or stub zones. If there's no trust, you can't migrate.